# Attempted to disable autoreset - now the voltage regulator only outputs 4.0v

Tags: voltage

I followed [the guide from the Arduino website](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection), by placing a 10uF capacitor between GND and Reset. However, now the voltage regulator only provides 4v (Vin=13V). It correctly has 5V when being powered via USB.

What happened? Isn't there a 10k resistor between +5V and Reset that should prevent the chip from being overloaded? Or did the Reset pin sink the entire energy of the capacitor?

Comment: Is there anything else plugged into the Arduino?

Comment: Yes, but there wasn't any problems before. It's been working fine in full-time operation for several months, and all devices are powered by a seperate 7805.

Comment: How hot is the onboard LM1117 regulator?

Comment: Yes, the LM1117 5.0 is very hot. But I'm not sure if this is because some component, e.g. the ATmega chip, or a capacitor, has failed, and therefore whether it makes sense to try to replace the regulator.

Comment: It sounds like the regulator may be going into thermal shutdown. Without the capacitor does it right itself?

Comment: I've removed the GND-Reset capacitor even before asking this question, but the problem remains. The other capacitors are SMD mounted and not easy to remove. Perhaps there's no other way than to replace the whole board.

Comment: I assume you also tried removing all the other connected devices? Even though they are externally powered they may have a bearing on it.